# Read system call gives wrong count size?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have created a misc driver and has made a sample read function like this

```
static ssize_t test_read(struct file *file, char __user *buffer,
        size_t count, loff_t *ppos)
{
    pr_info("Count arg : %d\n",count);

    return ret;
}
```

I now try to read the device using a userspace code as shown below

```
uint64_t read_buff;
fread(&read_buff, sizeof(read_buff), 1, fp)
```

The dmesg log I get is

```
[ 1593.273163] Count arg : 4096
```

I was expecting it to be of the size of uint64_t. Could anybody point me why I get an unexpected value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that `fread()` tries to buffer some data for userland. I found [source code of one `fread()`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-167/stdio.subproj/fread.c) that buffers data (in `__srefill()`). So, it's OK for `fread()` to do so.

If you want to avoid such unexpected results, lower one level down and work with `read()` function in userland.